# Content types & ubercart

Tags: ubercart

I have another question about ubercart. I have a content Type hotel & a content type tript (city trips etc) that people can buy, (just one price). I really don't know if it is possible to add my content type to ubercart so i do not have to add this all again manually. 
I hope this question is clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that if you go to `admin/store/products/classes` and add a class where the Class ID is the same as the machine name of the content type that Ubercart will pick it up as a product type.

Comment: Ok thank you, now I have the possible to create a new content with the content type I used as class AND my already made content types are adjusted. Thanks Malks. 
Maybe I have another question, There is a different price for the product in each period, but where do I have the possibility to add dates and prices for this dates?

Comment: Yes, that definitely sounds like a new question that should be asked separately.