# Ubercart with different dates/prices

Tags: ubercart, datetime

Ok guys, I have made a product class with the same name as the machine name from 1 contentType, SO now all the items =(holidays) are now bookable/ready to buy. 
I have one trip to thailand with a price of 1000 euro. This price depends on the hotel choice and the departure date. I thought to work with checkboxes for the hotels but I don't know what to do with the departure dates because every week has a different price and a different hotel.

Comment: To be more clear. I have a package called happy thailand roundtrip. users must be able to book this. So when they clicked on the buy now button, they come on a page where they can choose there departure date with their own prices (only a few dates are available).       Sometimes it is possible that a roundtrips has more hotels so the user had to choose in with hotel he has to stay (also different prices) Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: I think the question is interesting, but you would have bigger chances to get answers if you accepted any answers you got to any of the questions you asked... Like here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/17064/2368 . 
Btw., have you already tried "uc_hotel"? http://drupal.org/project/uc_hotel